# How can I get a picture only, not a picture on an entire page in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

I want to have the same effect in ConTeXt as the following effect in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That is, I want the result of a picture only, not a picture on an entire page. Could anyone tell me how I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a page which is cropped to its contents use [`\start...\stopTeXpage`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startTEXpage).  The `\startTEXpage` directive also acts as an implicit `\starttext`, so if your document is supposed to contain only a single page with a drawing, the following is enough:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\startTEXpage
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage
```

---

If the fitted page is supposed to contain a MetaFun drawing, there is an even shorter way to do it:  [`\start...\stopMPpage`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startMPpage).

```
\startMPpage
draw fullsquare xyscaled (2cm,3cm) ;  
\stopMPpage
```

Answer (score 1):

The corrected answer is as follows, according to the advice of Wolfgang Schuster.

```
% example.tex
\usemodule[tikz]

\setupTEXpage[pagestate=start]

\starttext

\startTEXpage
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage

\startTEXpage
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage

\startTEXpage
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

After several trials and erros, I found out how multiple fitted pages can be produced, so I would like to share it with others here.

```
% example.tex
\usemodule[tikz]

\setcounter[userpage][0]

\starttext

\incrementcounter[userpage]
\startTEXpage
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage

\incrementcounter[userpage]
\startTEXpage
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage

\incrementcounter[userpage]
\startTEXpage
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage

\stoptext
```

The following is how to get each page from the resulted .pdf file to the .svg file.

```
$ context example.tex

$ pdf2svg
Usage: pdf2svg <in file.pdf> <out file.svg> [<page no>]

$ pdf2svg example.pdf example-1.svg 1
$ pdf2svg example.pdf example-2.svg 2
$ pdf2svg example.pdf example-3.svg 3

$ ls -l example-?.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 philos philos 1039  Jun 10 15:21 example-1.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 philos philos  735  Jun 10 15:21 example-2.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 philos philos  939  Jun 10 15:21 example-3.svg
```

Comment: Why add `incrementcounter`?

Comment: I had to add `\setcounter[userpage][0]` and `\incrementcounter[userpage]`, because without them the page numbering strangely is 1, 1, 2 not 1, 2, 3, as of ConTeXt 1.01. 

I don't know why but it works anyway.

Comment: @PhilosKim To increment the page counter for the `TEXpage` environment use `\startTEXpage[pagestate=start]` at each use of the environment or add `\setupTEXpage[pagestate=start]` at the begin of your document.